# What does a colon before a literal in an SQL statement mean?

Tags: php, mysql, yii

What does it mean to use "**:**" before a variable ?

For example, `:userId` in this code:

```
public function removeUser($userId)
{
 $command = Yii::app()->db->createCommand();
 $command->delete(
 'tbl_project_user_assignment',
 'user_id=:userId AND project_id=:projectId',
 array(':userId'=>$userId,':projectId'=>$this->id));
}
```

This is PHP,MySQL code in Yii framework.

Comment: It indicates a bind variable for prepared statements.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The colon is a common character that indicates a placeholder for a variable value in a SQL statement. In this case, the those placeholders are getting replaced by the value of `userId` and `project_id` at runtime. This is great for avoiding SQL injection vulnerabilities.

Answer (score 3):

**:userId** is a placeholder

According to Yii's documentation for [SQL statement](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCommand#bindValue-detail):

> For a prepared statement using named placeholders, this will be a
>   parameter name of the form **:name**.

Answer (score 0):

As thaidiotguy mentions, it's a character commenly used with prepared statements especially with PDO. In PDO the colon tells that the following is a named parameter.